# How to submit a spark job using pythonOpearator and BranchPythonOperator in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I want to write a DAG file using BranchPjthonOpeator to execute a task based on condition.

Task1: should be executed only on sunday
Task2: should be executed daily

Task will contain a command to submit spark job

I am looking for a sample DAG file

Answer (score 1):

The `BranchPythonOpeator` isn't needed here. If you want to use branching you can use `BranchDayOfWeekOperator` as:

```
from airflow.operators.weekday import BranchDayOfWeekOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.providers.apache.spark.operators.spark_submit import SparkSubmitOperator
from airflow.utils.weekday import WeekDay


from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2021, 8, 19),
}

with DAG('stackoverflow_question',
         default_args=default_args,
         schedule_interval='@daily',
         ) as dag:

    branch_op = BranchDayOfWeekOperator(
        follow_task_ids_if_true="sunday_task",
        follow_task_ids_if_false="end_task",
        week_day=WeekDay.SUNDAY,
        use_task_execution_day=False,  #Change to True if you want to compare to DAG execution_date
        task_id="branch_task"
    )

    sunday_op = SparkSubmitOperator(
        application="${SPARK_HOME}/examples/src/main/python/task1.py",
        task_id="sunday_task"
    )
    daily_op = SparkSubmitOperator(
        application="${SPARK_HOME}/examples/src/main/python/task2.py",
        task_id="daily_task"
    )

    end_op = DummyOperator(task_id="end_task")

    daily_op >> branch_op >> [sunday_op, end_op]
```

[image]

Personally I don't like to use branch operators when there isn't a real case of branching. Note that I added here `DummyOperator`. If there aren't at least 2 real branches to follow I prefer to use conditioning with `ShortCircuitOperator` as:

```
from airflow.operators.python import ShortCircuitOperator
from airflow.providers.apache.spark.operators.spark_submit import SparkSubmitOperator

from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, date


def is_sunday():
    # you can also compare to DAG execution_date if needed
    if date.today().isoweekday() == 6:  # 6 is Sunday
        return True
    return False

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2021, 8, 19),
}

with DAG('stackoverflow_question',
         default_args=default_args,
         schedule_interval='@daily',
         ) as dag:

    sunday_op = SparkSubmitOperator(
        application="${SPARK_HOME}/examples/src/main/python/task1.py",
        task_id="sunday_task"
    )
    daily_op = SparkSubmitOperator(
        application="${SPARK_HOME}/examples/src/main/python/task2.py",
        task_id="daily_task"
    )

    short_op = ShortCircuitOperator(
        task_id='is_sundy',
        python_callable=is_sunday,
    )

    daily_op >> short_op >> sunday_op
```

[image]

In this solution the `ShortCircuitOperator` will cause the downstream task to be executed only on Sunday, for the rest of the week it will be skipped.